# Kendo UI Core Listview Edit Template with Autocomplete TextBox(Kendo Autocomplete)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-listview

How to use the Kendo UI Autocomplete textbox inside the Listview Edit Template??While trying to apply the autocomplete option the text box not taking it.The requirement also includes a server side filtering option.This needs to be implemented in an ASP.NET MVC5 Web Application.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried to implement the same provided in the below link http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/editing. Here while editing the listitem i need  an Auto complete textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Kendo UI for Jquery and I have implemented something similar. Idea behind the implementation is that you have to add the autocomplete when you are editing the ListView.

I am sharing the "Edit Template" and "ListView JS" below.

I found the idea here http://jsfiddle.net/F4NvL/

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="editTemplate">
<div class="product-view k-widget">
    <dl>
        <dt>Product Name</dt>
        <dd>
            <label for="PAPC">Project Code<span class="k-icon k-i-star requiredstar" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Required"></span></label>
            <input type="text" required name="PAPC" validationMessage="Hotel is required" data-bind="value: ProjectCode" />
            <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="PAPC"></span>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <div class="edit-buttons">
        <a class="k-button k-update-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-i-check"></span></a>
        <a class="k-button k-cancel-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-i-cancel"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var listView = $("#lvPA").kendoListView({
        dataSource: datasrc,
        template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
        editTemplate: kendo.template($("#editTemplate").html()),
        edit: function (e) {
            var model = e.model;
            var item = $(e.item[0]);

            var projectcode = item.find('[name="PAPC"]'); //Get your element
            //Add a autocomplete here
            projectcode.kendoAutoComplete({
                valueTemplate: '<span>#:data.ProjectCode#</span>',
                template: projectTemplate,
                minLength: 3,
                autoWidth: true,
                dataTextField: "ProjectCode",
                dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    type: "GET",
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: ProjectAPI,
                        parameterMap: function (data, type) {

                            return { filter: $('[name="PAPC"]').val() };
                        }
                    },
                }),
                height: 200
            });
        }
    }).data("kendoListView");
```